# How do I identify the variable's name as a string from self?

Tags: ruby

I wrote a wrapper for the Ruby OpenStruct library. Using this wrapper, a user declares a variable like so:

```
example = RStruct.new()
```

I would like to access the variable's name like so:

```
example.name # => "example"
```

This would prove useful when operating from within a class and calling `self.name`

I built the `RStruct` class, so adding the name method wouldn't be hard. I'm looking to find the user's variable from `self`.

If any language can do it, it's Ruby, right?

Comment: Why do you assume the object is in a named variable? Or that it's in only one of them? :)

Comment: RStruct is a class I made that wraps OpenStruct and Redis. It's not in any existing ruby library. ------

If they're not using a named variable, that would be fine, but is there any way I can know? ------

Or if there are more than one references to the object, I would still like to be able to find out their names. Is that at all possible?

Comment: Are you trying to link a variable name to some structure in Redis?

Comment: I could have understood what you are trying to do if `name` were an instance method on `RStruct`. Why is it a class method? How can a particular instance be chosen from a class?

Comment: OpenStruct is a data structure written by Matz. It uses missing_method to create singleton methods based on an input: 
`require 'ostruct'; 
example = OpenStruct.new; 
example.property = value; 
example.property # => value;
`

I'm trying to replicate this, but instead of saving the results in a hash like OpenStruct does, I save them to Redis.

The name comes in because I'd like to have a specific namespace for the keys in redis, depending on what the user calls their instance. 

Sorry about the `RStruc.name`, I meant to say `example.name`. I would be calling this with self, though: `self.name`.

Comment: Afaik, this is not possible (short of doing something cheesy like iterating through all local variables)

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to do but maybe you can use `object_id` and/or saving name (for example to a instance variable)? I have played for some time and I made this: https://gist.github.com/nedzadarek/ce7dce40c9ed329c27f4 I hope it will helps.

Comment: @hobbs and everyone, he is asking the right thing, don't bash him. This is a very useful technique, and I've written a gem for it.

Comment: Thanks everyone! You've been very helpful. I was originally using `object_id`, but I think this is clearer. I'll use `NameMagic`. Have a good day!

Comment: Be aware that the present version breaks when you assign to the same constant twice (not that it would be a smiled-upon thing to do). This is remedied in the upcoming release.

Comment: Plus I just found one more bug in `#name_get_hook`, which is also remedied in the upcoming release.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This situation pops up in Ruby so often, that I have written a gem for it. What you normally would do in vanilla Ruby would be something like:

```
fred = Foobar.new( name: 'fred' )
```

Not only does "fred" repeat twice in the above line, but also you have to cater to the named parameter `:fred`, and you have to do chores such as writing `RStruct#name` method etc. If you `gem install y_support`, then you can write:

```
require 'y_support/name_magic'

class Foobar
  include NameMagic
end
```

And now:

```
Fred = Foobar.new
Fred.name #=> "Fred"
```

You are limited that only assignments to constants (starting with a capital letter) work to name a nameless object whose class includes `NameMagic`, but anyway "fred" should be capitalized. Ruby constants double up as capitalized proper names of things, and Ruby modules are sometimes also called namespaces. This is consistent with the behavior of naming classes by constant assignment, such as `Animal = Class.new`, also known as Ruby built-in constant magic.

---

**APPENDIX DESCRIBING NAME MAGIC FEATURES IN MORE DETAIL:**

`NameMagic` also provides a limited number of frequently used services related to naming. One that is often needed is the instance registry:

```
Foobar.instances
#=> [Fred]
```

The registry itself is a hash and can be accessed via:

```
Foobar.__instances__ # Don't modify this hash unless you know what you are doing.
```

A method much more useful than it seems is `#instance` method:

```
Foobar.instance "Fred"
#=> Fred
Foobar.instance Fred
#=> Fred
```

This method converts its parameter, be it a string, the object itself, or something else, into the corresponding object, and raises a `NameError` is there is no such instance.

`Array` is extended with `#names` method, so you can get the names of objects in an array easily (I confirmed to myself that this is an oft needed feature):

```
Foobar.instances.names
#=> ["Fred"]
```

`Hash` is extended with `#keys_to_names` method, so you can write `{ Fred => 42 }.keys_to_names` to switch from using objects to using their names. This one is not needed so often, but I did include it, since naming is intimately connected to hashing, a name is a kind of a hash function that is supposed to be meaningful to and easily memorized by humans. So much for extensions to the core classes. Other methods you can look up in the documentation include `Foobar.nameless_instances`, `Foobar.forget`, `Foobar.forget_nameless_instances`, `Foobar.forget_all_instances` (to allow the disused objects to be GCed, that's just for advanced use and to allay hypothetical complaints about the gem eating up memory).

The current version of the gem breaks badly when you assign to a constant twice, which is already remedied in the next scheduled version, whose release is held back by a dependency (another gem of mine). Also, thanks for pointing me towards a way to suppress the annoying warnings generated whe one touches some obscure constants in the deep namespace.

The gem allows also naming by a more standard method, using `:name` parameter rather than constant assignment, so this is one more chore the gem user doesn't have to do:

```
Foobar.new name: "Joe"
Foobar.instances #=> [Fred, Joe]
```

Or using `#name=` setter.

```
x = Foobar.new
x.name = "Sam"
Foobar.instances #=> [Fred, Joe, Sam]
```

The final useful feature I want to introduce here are two hooks, `#name_set_hook` and `#name_get_hook`. The first one if very useful to validate and/or modify the suggested name. Also, there is a good chance you will need to execute some code not upon instantiation (because the instances using `name_magic` are born nameless), but only when the name is known, such as registering the object under its name into various collections of yours. `#name_set_hook` is the place to put that code in. This feature is a bit precarious, in the sense that you have to know the rules:

---

1. The block is expected to be ternary, with ordered arguments name, instance and previous name.
2. The block must return a valid name, which will be used instead of the suggested name. This gives one the opportunity to modify the name, but if you don't want to modify it, you still must return the unmodified version.
3. The block code must refrain from directly or indirectly triggering an inquiry about the name so-far unnamed instance, or endless loop will ensue. In particular, `#inspect` and `#to_s` method must not be invoked for the nameless instance. Doing it anywhere else is OK, but not in this block.

---

```
Foobar.name_set_hook { |name, instance, old_name|
  puts "Name #{name} was requsted for object #{instance.object_id}." # not "#{instance}",
  # because "#{instance}" would invoke instance.to_s method.
  puts "Such name is not acceptable to our church."
  modified_name = "#{name}x"
  puts "The name will be #{modified_name}."
  # notify your tables that the object has just been named with modified_name
  acceptable_name # the block must return the name to be used, even if it doesn't modify it
}

Nathan = Foobar.new
#=> Name Nathan was requsted for object 76778240.
#=> Such name is not acceptable to our church.
#=> The name will be Nathanx.

Foobar.instances #=> [Fred, Joe, Sam, Nathanx]
```

Much less useful hook is `#name_get_hook`. It's only useful when you want the names have more than one alternative ways of presentation an you want to choose a particular one. For example, physical units can be held as all-caps constants, such as

```
class Unit; include NameMagic end
GRAM, METRE, SECOND = Unit.new, Unit.new, Unit.new
#=> [GRAM, METRE, SECOND]
```

But you might want them to present themselves in lower case:

```
Unit.name_get_hook { |name| name.downcase }
Unit.instances
#=> [gram, metre, second]
```

Method `#instance` recognizes both cases:

```
Unit.instance "metre"
#=> metre
Unit.instance "METRE"
#=> metre
```

But internally, the stored name is still the upper case version, which we can confirm by investigating the instance registry hash accessible via `#__instances__` method.

```
Unit.__instances__[ Unit.instance( "metre" ) ]
#=> "METRE"
```

This was my actual use case that inspired me to add `#name_get_hook` feature, which is necessary because the names have to start with a capital letter, but the convention for units is to write them in all small letters. In other words, the hidden rule of `#name_get_hook` use is that there must be an unambiguous way to derive the actual name from the presented alternative form.

The gem's Github repo is https://github.com/boris-s/y_support. And now I should pull myself together and put this text into the README file lol.

Comment: Great gem! Just so you know, I've found that it issues the following warning: `namespace_methods.rb:245:in 'const_get': Use RbConfig instead of obsolete and deprecated Config.`

Comment: @Kites I've found the same error. It was on Ruby 2.0. On Ruby 1.9.3 It is not working at all. Aside that, very clever trick using, as you named it, "Ruby built-in constant magic".

Comment: @DarekNędza I've found a workaround for Ruby 2: if you change `$stderr` to `$stdout.dup` and then change it back again after you call the name method you effectively bypass the error message. I used a superclass with the NameMagic module, rewriting the name in the `RStruct` class to incorporate this hack before calling `super`. Not pretty, but it works.

Comment: Actually, you've got to use `$stdin.dup`.

Comment: @Kites, that's not of my own making. What the gem does is quite difficult. Matz [almost promised](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/7149) a hook `#const_assigned`, and before we have it, I need to search whole object space for new constant assigments, so don't tak use of this constant magic in the innermost loop of your algorithm :-). It seems that some constants in the deep namespace are dynamically generated (perhaps by `const_missing`?) and therefrom the warning that `Config` is a taboo name. As for the version, 2.x is very close to 1.9.3 and is a standard already anyway.

Comment: @Kites, what, you found a workaround? I didn't know this was possible, I'll incorporate it in the gem, lemme make a memo of it.

Comment: OK, your approach works. I just changed `$stdin.dup` to `nil.tap { |o| def o.write *args; fail IOError end }`, and I rescue the `IOError` in the code that searches the deep namespace. It will be out with the next version of `y_support`.

Answer (score 1):

Variables aren't objects. You can't do anything with them except assign to them and dereference them.

```
example.name
```

will *always* mean "dereference `example` and send the message `name` to the result of dereferencing `example`", it will *never* mean "send the message `name` to the variable `example`", because a) that would lead to an ambiguity, and b) variables aren't objects, so you *can't* send messages to them.